# What’s a good way to showcase “app discovery” on a platform?

Tags: usability, gui-design, affordance, discovery

A big part of our USP is to take the structure data on recipes and allow additional functionalities on top of it. 
[Here’s an example:](http://norecipes.com/green-tomato-gratin)
[image]

Clicking on the ***Print & Other Apps*** exposes “apps” like unit conversion, nutritional info, print etc.

[image]

We intend to build more functional like servings meter, calorimeter etc. and expose this to third parties.

A huge challenge we are facing is the *discoverability of these “apps”* . Few people realize the richness of the functionality behind the **Print & Other apps** button.

We tried fixing this with a pop over
[image]
but the CTRs are still in the low 0.07% range

We’ve been discussing approaches like
[image]
but fear clutter. Our bigger problem is non-uniformity in styles due to theming (For example, here are two blogs on the platform: [ALittleBitofSpice](http://www.alittlebitofspice.com/), [InduGetsCooking](http://www.indugetscooking.com/)) and how we can deal with this in the responsive mobile world.

How can we showcase the power of different apps to the blog audience and enable **serendipitous discovery**?

Comment: I admit that the functionallity of the button is quite unclear. If that can help you, the printer icon lead me to believe that the other "apps" were all related to printing (until I read the full post). Maybe try not showing "print" as the main function of the button?

Comment: Thanks Oliver. Point noted. Btw, can you check out one of the posts on: http://norecipes.com/arroz-con-pollo-recipe

Answer (score 1):

#### Provide links / show buttons in context

Assuming the apps you want to showcase are actually relevant to the user in this scenario (and you're not just trying to shoehorn in services for the sake of it), then just *show the app buttons/links in locations relevant to their utility*.

So nutritional information would appear with the other metadata at the top of the recipe. Unit conversion would appear where the ingredients/units are listed, etc., etc.

Print (which probably shouldn't be considered an "app") should go where people expect it - in the 'secondary actions' area, in the top right of the page.